# Taylor Expansions -- Approximations

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

Given that $R^2 = z^2 + \rho^2$, I wish to show that,

> $$ \ln \Bigg [ \frac{\sqrt{(L - z)^2 + \rho^2} + L - z}{\sqrt{(L + z)^2 + \rho^2} - L - z} \Bigg ], \tag{3.30} $$

is approximately equal to:

> $$ \ln \Bigg [ \frac{1 - z/R + L/R}{1 - z/R - L/R} \Bigg ] \tag{3.35} . $$

if $z \ggg L$. But I am unable to get this result. I get:

> $$ \ln \Bigg [ \frac{1 - 2z/L + R^2/2L^2}{R^2/2L^2} \Bigg ], $$

by the usual trick: take $L^2$ common with the square. Use the Taylor Exapansion. Take $L$ common in both the numerator and denominator and cancel it out.

What am I missing?

---

Edit:

Here's the snippet from the textbook. I have underlined the relevant portion for your reference:

[image]

Please note that I dropped all the constants in my post. I hope the snippet is readable. If not, access the book at: http://shrek.unideb.hu/~adamkardos/temp/boox/Modern%20electrodynamics.pdf

Please correct if I am making any mistake.

Comment: It really doesn't look like what you want to show. Are you sure you have the correct expression: letters, signs, etc.?

Comment: As  DonAntonio commented, I wonder if the expression is correct. Since $\rho^2=R^2-z^2$, the numerator is $\sqrt{L^2-2 L z+R^2}+L-z$ and the denominator is $\sqrt{L^2+2 L z+R^2}-L-z$ and the minus sign in the radical of numerator makes problems to me.

Comment: @DonAntonio Check the edit.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Check the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what they did...these physicists really are...gees!

The gist is that $\;z>>L\;$, so $\;\sqrt{(L\pm z)^2+\rho^2}\approx\sqrt{z^2+\rho^2}=R\;$ (becasue this is going to be the argument of a logarithm), and then they just did divide by $\;R\;$ ...!:

$$\frac{\sqrt{(L-z)^2+\rho^2}+L-z}{\sqrt{(L-z)+\rho^2}-L-z}\approx\frac{R+L-z}{R-L+z}\stackrel{:R}=\frac{1+\frac LR-\frac zR}{1-\frac LR+\frac zR}$$

...and that's all!

Comment: Oh, okay. Is there a correct/mathematically sound way, according to my initial approach perhaps, to reproduce the result without simply dropping terms.

Comment: @JunaidAftab If you mean using Taylor series and etc. I don't think you can reach the above: that's what I did and I got something very similar, perhaps even identical (I didn't check completely) to what you got. I think they're just doing a crude approximation.

Comment: Do you have any problem with physicists ? If yes, I am one. Just joking for sure (except that I am a physicist). As you say, this is the only way to arrive there. I became crazy with Taylor series including $\sqrt{-L}$ and other horrible things. Cheers ;-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Salute, mon ami...le physicien.

Comment: So good to have you on board. Be sure, amigo mio, that, at this point, I am very serious. Un abrazo fuerte.